# Completeness of $(C_c^k(\mathbb R^n),\left\|\cdot\right\|_{k,\mathbb R^n})$.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

It's well-known that $(C^k(\overline{\Omega}),\left\|\cdot\right\|_{k,\overline{\Omega}})$ is a Banach space if $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ is open, connected and bounded.
I want to study some properties of the unbounded situation $(C_c^k(\mathbb R^n),\left\|\cdot\right\|_{k,\mathbb R^n})$.
Here is my problem (I'm not sure whether this is true):

> Define the $k$-norm $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{k,\mathbb R^n}$ for $C_c^k(\mathbb R^n)$ by
> \begin{align*}
>   \left\|u\right\|_{k,\mathbb R^n} =\max_{|\alpha|\le k}\max_{x\in\mathbb R^n} |\partial^\alpha u(x)|
>   \quad \forall u\in C_c^k(\mathbb R^n)
>  \end{align*}
> and we extend $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{k,\mathbb R^n}$ to $C^k(\mathbb R^n)$ by
> \begin{align*}
>   \left\|\cdot\right\|_{k,\mathbb R^n}: C^k(\mathbb R^n)&\to [0,+\infty],
>   \quad u\mapsto \max_{|\alpha|\le k}\sup_{x\in\mathbb R^n} |\partial^\alpha u(x)|
>  \end{align*}
> Let $(f_i)_{i\ge 1}$ be a Cauchy sequence of functions in $(C_c^k(\mathbb R^n),\left\|\cdot\right\|_{k,\mathbb R^n})$.
> Then there exists $f\in C^k(\mathbb R^n)$ such that
> \begin{align*}
>   \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=f(x) \quad \forall x\in \mathbb R^n
>  \end{align*}
> Furthermore,
> \begin{align}
>   \lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|f_n-f\right\|_{k,\mathbb R^n}=0 \tag{1}
>  \end{align}

**My attempy**

It's obvious that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ exists for each $x\in \mathbb R^n$, and we put
\begin{align*}
  f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)\quad \forall x\in \mathbb R^n
 \end{align*}
In the next we prove that $f\in C^k(\mathbb R^n)$.
It suffices to prove that for each ball $B\subset \mathbb R^n$, $f\in C^k(\overline B)$.
Similarly, we define the $k$-norm $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{k,\overline{B} }$ for $C^k(\overline B)$ by
\begin{align*}
  \left\|u\right\|_{k,\overline{B} } =\max_{|\alpha|\le k}\max_{x\in \overline{B}} |\partial^\alpha u(x)|
  \quad \forall u\in C^k(\overline B)
 \end{align*}
Note that $(f_i|_{\overline B})$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(C^k(\overline{B}),\left\|\cdot\right\|_{k,\overline{B}})$, and
hence via the completeness we know that $(f_i|_{\overline B})$ converges to $f|_{\overline{B}}$ in
$(C^k(\overline{B}),\left\|\cdot\right\|_{k,\overline{B}})$ and that $f\in C^k(\overline B)$.

It seems well to prove the conclusion except (1). But I got stuck on (1), and I'm not sure whether (1) is true.

I would highly appreciate it if you could share any thoughts on how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: take $k=0$ and $n=1$, and find test functions that converge to $e^{-x}$ uniformly on one side. For higher $k$, just integrate.

Comment: Note that $C_k(\mathbb R^n)$ is not a normed space with respect to sup-norms as it contains unbounded functions as well. You have to use $C_0^k$.

Comment: As mentioned in other comments, if you mean by $C_c^k(\mathbb R^n)$ the space of compactly supported $k$-smooth functions, this is not true since this a dense subspace of $C_0(\mathbb{R}^{n}$. The problem is not proving (1) but that this $f$ need not have compact support. If you are satisfied with having a metric instead of a norm you can get a complete linear metric space $C^k(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of (1) does not differ from proofs of completeness of $C_0(X)$.
Take $\epsilon>0$. Then there is $N$ such that for all $m,n>N$
$$
|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\le \epsilon.
$$
Now let $m\to\infty$. This implies
$$
|f(x)-f_m(x)|\le \epsilon
$$
for all $m>N$.